# Can I build a Yagi antenna for my Baofeng UV-5R?

Tags: antenna, antenna-construction, baofeng, yagi

I would like to build a Yagi antenna for my Baofeng UV-5R, but I'm a total newbie when it comes to amateur radios. The antenna will be for UHF and shouldn't be too long (like 1.5 meters max).

So my questions are: how many elements should I use? I'm little bit worried about Baofeng getting overloaded, I don't want to build an antenna that won't be usable with the Baofeng.

How exactly do you connect it to the Baofeng?

Comment: the larger elements of your yagi will be roughly half a wavelength – at UHF, that'll be in the order of half a meter. You'd connect that antenna with a coax cable to the antenna port of your radio.

Comment: There's **a lot** of yagi online calculators ([example](https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/yagi_uda_antenna_DL6WU.php)), and your dimensional requirements indicate you'd have at most 5 element yagi at 145 MHz.

Comment: [Related question and answers here](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/1469/what-antenna-on-a-baofeng-uv-5r-pro-will-give-me-better-reception).

Comment: I slightly edited the title of your question. If what I did is not acceptable to you, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience UV-5R doesn't work well with external antennas. I'm not sure what is the reason, but from what I know it has something to do with the fact that most of RF part of this radio is implemented in one chip.

I have an experience of using a 3 element yagi with another 5W radio, Kenwood TH-D72A. 3 elements for 2m band and 5 elements for 70cm band is enough for making SAT QSOs. Kenwood TH-D72A is a little difficult to find these days, also this is not the cheapest radio. Something like Yaesu FT-60R or Yaesu FT-65R should work well with a yagi antenna, are not too expensive an are easy to find.

Comment: This sounds like the outer shell of the antenna connector is not grounded. If so, then hand capacitance must be the "ground". Rats, I was looking forward to using an external antenna myself.

Comment: The output of a friend's UV-5R into a 50$\Omega$ dummy load met specifications. Why would a 50$\Omega$ antenna not behave the same?

Answer (score 0):

The yagi will not hurt your radio if it is made for the right frequency. I would recommend making a small 3 element yagi that you hold in your hand.

You remove the antenna that comes with the radio and then plug a cable in. The other end of the cable goes to the Yagi.

Comment: This is likely a good answer, *provided* that [Aleksander](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/15411/8717) is mistaken. Unless someone else comes along with a different personal experience, I tend to believe that he is right.

Comment: Some baofengs have been reported to have poor front end filters.  Those radios might be helped by a narrow band antenna, but will be hurt by a wideband antenna with high gain.  So it could go either way, depending on how you build the antenna.   Rumor is that their filters are getting better.

Answer (score 0):

The antenna on [this page](https://www.instructables.com/id/Yagi-Antenna-for-the-70-Cm-Band-430-440-MHz-by-F4H/) seems doable and does not appear to require soldering.

Comment: Please add enough information _in your answer_ to answer the question. Links are good, but an answer should remain useful even if the links break.

Comment: OK, will do.  Thank you.